# Multidimensional variable length array in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector

```
void drawTable(int arg[], int length);

int main()
{
    int length=0;
    int counter=0;
    int *pointer2ArrSize = new int[length];

    cout << "Enter length of array: " << endl;
    cin >> length;

    do{
            for(int j=0; j<length; j++){
                cout << "Enter array elements: \n";
                cin >> pointer2ArrSize[j];
                cout << "You entered: " << pointer2ArrSize[j] << " in position: "
                     << j+1
                     << endl; 
            counter++;
            }
           cout << drawTable(pointer2ArrSize[j],length) << endl;
    }while(!counter == length);

    return 0;
}

void drawTable(int arg[], int length){
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
        cout << arg[i] << " ";
        cout << '/n';
    }
}
```

> error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]

My goal is to display a 2D variable length array. I want the user to define the length of the array and the elements in it. However, am not too familiar with vectors yet. how could I approach this?

Comment: Learning about vectors would be a good start.

Comment: "Multidimensional variable length array in C++" - aka `std::vector`...

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> cout << drawTable(pointer2ArrSize[j],length) << endl;
> ```

is wrong since the argument type for `drawTable` is `int*` and you are passing `pointer2ArrSize[j]` to it, which is of type `int`.

You need to use

```
cout << drawTable(pointer2ArrSize, length) << endl;
```

---

More importantly, use of

```
int *pointer2ArrSize = new int[length];
cout << "Enter length of array: " << endl;
cin >> length;
```

is wrong.

The array will not be resized to `length` after you accept its value from the user. Consequently, `pointer2ArrSize` will continue to be an array of size `0`. Since `pointer2ArrSize` continues to be an array of size `0`, any attempt to access its elements will result in undefined behavior.

Move the line that allocates memory after you have accepted the input value for `length`.

```
cout << "Enter length of array: " << endl;
cin >> length;
int *pointer2ArrSize = new int[length];
```

It will be better still to use `std::vector`. Then, you don't have to worry about memory allocation and deallocation.

```
cout << "Enter length of array: " << endl;
cin >> length;
std::vector<int> pointer2ArrSize(length);
```

Of course, you should change `drawTable` to accept a `std::vector<int>`.

```
void drawTable(std::vector<int> const& arg);
```

There won't be the need for `length` as a second argument to `drawTable` since you can get the size of the array from the `std::vector`.